# How to ensure router actor with "group mode" already associate remote routees?

Tags: scala, akka

For router actor with "group mode", we new a series of actors in advance, and then we will use `actorOf` to associate one router with remote routees.

In fact, it internal will use actorSelection, my question is: `how to assure the association already finish?`

For actorSelection, we can use `resolveOne` to make sure the selection is successful, then send message. But how about router actor? See following code, how to assure `line2` associate with remote routees before send message to it, just like line `line1` does?

```
package local
import akka.actor._
import akka.routing.RoundRobinGroup
import akka.util.Timeout
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory
import scala.util.{Failure, Success}

object Local extends App {
  val config = ConfigFactory.parseString(s"akka.remote.netty.tcp.port=2251")
  val system = ActorSystem("LocalSystem", config.withFallback(ConfigFactory.load()))
  system.actorOf(Props[LocalActor], "LocalActor")
  val config2 = ConfigFactory.parseString(s"akka.remote.netty.tcp.port=2252")
  val system2 = ActorSystem("LocalSystem2", config2.withFallback(ConfigFactory.load()))
  system2.actorOf(Props[LocalActor2], "LocalActor2")
}
class LocalActor extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case _ => println("hi")
  }
}
class LocalActor2 extends Actor {
  import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
  implicit val timeout = Timeout(5 seconds)
  val a = context.actorSelection("akka.tcp://LocalSystem@127.0.0.1:2251/user/LocalActor")
  a.resolveOne().onComplete { // line 1
    case Success(actor) => println("ready")
      a ! 1
    case Failure(ex) => println("not ready")
  }
  val paths = List("akka.tcp://LocalSystem@127.0.0.1:2251/user/LocalActor")
  val b = context.actorOf(RoundRobinGroup(paths).props(), "LocalActorRouter") // line 2
  b ! 1
  def receive = {
    case _ =>
  }
}
```